# How to add items to array based on conditional

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Instead of doing a nested conditional, is there a cleaner more efficient way of achieving this:

- if option === 3, add both the nearbyLocations and recentSearches object to array
- if option == 1, add only the recentSearches
- else (or option === 2), add only nearbyLocations object

See below for my code. Thank you!

```
const results = option === 3 ? [...state.nearbyLocations, ...recentSearches] : option === 1 ? [...recentSearches] : [...state.nearbyLocations]
```

Comment: Is `option` really a string, and can it have only those three values? Would 0 be a valid value as well?

Comment: Perhaps [Switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) might be something you want to take a look it if you don't want nested conditionals.

Comment: I updated the code above so that option is an integer. There is a 0 or Default value where I'd like to return empty array []

Comment: IMO never use nested conditionals. Use switches of if statements to preserve readability

Comment: @Mike Good, my answer does just that :-) The code in your question didn't consider the `0` case correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use multiple spread elements that depending on the options contribute a value to the result or not:

```
const results = [
    ...(option === 3 || option === 2 ? state.nearbyLocations : []),
    ...(option === 3 || option === 1 ? recentSearches : []),
];
```

or with bit masks - as that is what your options essentially match - do

```
const results = [
    ...(option & 0b10 ? state.nearbyLocations : []),
    ...(option & 0b01 ? recentSearches : []),
];
```

Comment: Why are you adding the spread operator to ...option? The spread operator is for ...state.nearbyLocations

Comment: @Mike The spread syntax encompasses the whole ternary expression. I'll use parenthesis to make it more clear, but they are not necessary.

Comment: Ah nice - this works perfectly. Much cleaner than what I had originally. Thank you!

Comment: Awwww. Exacly what I would suggest. When answer isn't clear, ask different question (what is the situation when I add ...). Please, don't use bitmap - bad practice! ...unless it's code golf :)

Comment: @Tymek Why do you think bitmaps are a bad practice? Because few people understand bitwise operations? Imo they're perfect for this and probably even how `option` was designed - as per the OP, for a value of `0` nothing should be returned, for `1` the one, for `2` the other, and for `3` both. It's not hard to discover the pattern :-)

Comment: It's not about can you understand it, it's about how fast you can process it. There are hard things that many people don't understand, but I can quickly snap to what I was thinking when writing it (functional programming?). Some things aren't like that for me. Why not use other weird things in JS: `~` operator, `typeof NaN` etc. I'd get yield at if I write code like this at work. KISS rule.

Comment: @Tymek well especially if there are more than just two option bits, the bitwise AND *is* the short and simple solution :-)

Comment: Short, "simple", and (time) expensive. I'd just never do it to my `cwrkrs&|emplyr` ;) For more than 2 just create some additional variables, name them. Use full `if` statements and `let results` with `push`. You're smart, answer is great, I just don't agree with obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, it's better to use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement:

```
var results = [];
switch (option) {
    case 3:
        results.push(...state.nearbyLocations, ...recentSearches);
        break;
    case 1:
        results.push(...recentSearches);
        break;
    case 2:
        results.push(...state.nearbyLocations);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use spread syntax for the method call? You shouldn't need `apply`, and you shouldn't need array literals.

Comment: @Bergi I'm sorry, that's how I believed the OP wanted it pushed to the array. How should I best do this? Feel free to edit my answer with the correct syntax if you feel the need.

Comment: Ok done, now it should be equivalent to what the OP was doing :-)